# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error lottery program/ Uncompilable source code error

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and in creating a program to print 6 random numbers for a lottery ticket, i am receiving an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error that i cannot figure out how to fix.  Here is what I have.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DebugMeOne {

    static int[] lottoNumbers = new int[6];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        generateNumbers();
        printNumbers();
    }

    private static void generateNumbers()
    {
        int ticketNumber;
        Random generateRandomNumber = new Random();

        for (int count = 0; count < lottoNumbers.length + 1; count++)
        {
            ticketNumber = 1 + generateRandomNumber.nextInt(59);
            lottoNumbers[count] = ticketNumber;
       }
    }

    private static void printNumbers()
    {
       for (int count = 0; count < lottoNumbers.length + 1; count++)
        {
           if (count < 5)
               if (count == 4)
                   System.out.print(lottoNumbers[count]);
               else
                    System.out.print(lottoNumbers[count] + ", ");
           else
               System.out.println("\nPower Ball: "
                                    + lottoNumbers[count]);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have another program i had to create for the same thing, just a little bit different code. I am getting an error in that as well:

```
public class Lottery {

    static ArrayList<Integer> lottoNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int MAX_NUMBERS = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        generateNumbers();
        printNumbers();
    }

    private static void generateNumbers()
    {
        int ticketNumber;
        Random generateRandomNumber = new Random();

        for (int count = 0; count < MAX_NUMBERS; count++)
        {
            ticketNumber = 1 + generateRandomNumber.nextInt(59);
            lottoNumbers.add(new Integer(ticketNumber));
        }
    }

    private static void printNumbers()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for( Integer number : numbers )  // enhanced for loop
        {
           if (count < 5)
               if (count == 4)
                   System.out.print(number);
               else
                    System.out.print(number + ", ");
           else
           {
               System.out.println("\nPower Ball: " + number);
               count++;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

In this i am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable numbers
  location: class debugmetwo.DebugMeTwo
    at debugmetwo.DebugMeTwo.printNumbers(DebugMeTwo.java:52)
    at debugmetwo.DebugMeTwo.main(DebugMeTwo.java:34)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: And the error says what?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Comment: What about the stack trace after that? (lines starting with "at")? Also, why isn't that in the question?

Comment: Sorry, as i said, i am new to this. The solutions given to me worked fine! thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop count is exceeding over the array's `length`. Both the for loops should be run like

```
for (int count = 0; count < lottoNumbers.length; count++)
```

Also, you shouldn't hardcode your `length` values (5, 4) used in your `count` comparisons for printing commas. Use the `length` property as

```
for (int count = 0; count < lottoNumbers.length; count++)
 {
   if (count < lottoNumbers.length - 1) {
       System.out.print(lottoNumbers[count]);
       System.out.print(count == lottoNumbers.length - 2 ? "" : ", ");
   } else {
       System.out.println("\nPower Ball: "
                            + lottoNumbers[count]);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop's condition should be :

```
for (int count = 0; count < lottoNumbers.length; count++)
```

The valid indices of `lottoNumbers` are from `0` to `lottoNumbers.length - 1`.